# Circumvent UIImagePicker Preview Window

Tags: ios, image, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, picker

How can I avoid the "Preview" window displayed to a user using an image picker regardless of the editing property? I just want to save the photo directly to the Camera Roll, and then allow the user to continue taking pictures.  Thanks.

Comment: thats like asking "how to I turn editing off without turning editing off?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to switch to a **AVCaptureDevice** approach

Answer (score 0):

Try `imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;` to disable cropping before your app gets the image back.

Comment: Ok, but how can I simply save the picture and allow the user to take more without releasing the picker?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```